# Why is the external variable used in the Task.Run argument considered unassigned?

Tags: c#, variable-assignment

In the following code:

```
async Task<int> Foo()
{
    int result;
    await Task.Run( () => { result = 9999; } );
    return result;
}
```

VS 2015 reports an error: "Use of unassigned local variable 'result'". So, let's make a change:

```
async Task<int> Foo()
{
    int result = 0;
    await Task.Run( () => { result = 9999;} );
    return result;
}
```

And voila. Not only does this compile, it'll return 9999 (as expected).

Why is `result` considered to be unassigned in the first example when it is obviously assigned in the `Task.Run` statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler isn't smart enough to know whether the lambda `() => result = 999` is going to be executed, because it does not know the internals of `Task.Run`.

Because it doesn't know if the lambda will run it wants you to guarantee that `result` has a value assigned to it before the `return` expression.